# X probability function

Tags: probability, combinatorics

3 men and 3 women sits on chairs numbered 1-6.

let X be the lowest number which a woman sits on.

what is the probability function of X?

I know X=1,2,3,4 and all the combinations is 64, but Im not sure how to start counting all the options

Comment: Show your attempt or ideas...

Comment: It's pretty easy to split the problems into cases... how many ways are there for a woman to be 1st? 2nd (but not 1st)? 3rd (but not 1st or 2nd)? 4th (etc...)?

Comment: This is not a "homework done for you" website. Ask,what part of the question you don't understand

Comment: let say the first is woman so (1/6)*(3c2)?

Comment: Ordering like WMMWMW gives $\binom{6}{3}=20$ possibilities. Do you understand that? You could say the $3$ chairs meant for a woman are picked out of $6$ chairs in total.

Answer (score 1):

We solve a more general problem. The solution is likely to be understood only after a number of more concrete problems of this type have been solved.

We have $n$ chairs, numbered $1$ to $n$ and select $k$ of them. Let $X$ be the number of the smallest chair selected. What is the probability that $X=i$?

The possible values of $X$ are $1$ to $n-k+1$.  There are $\binom{n}{k}$ equally likely ways to choose $k$ chairs. Now we count the number of *favourables*, that is, the number of ways to choose $k$ chairs so that the smallest is $i$.

We must choose $k-1$ chairs from the chairs numbered $i+1$ to $n$. There are $n-i$ such chairs, so the number of favourables is $\binom{n-i}{k-1}$.

Comment: so I think the solution for my problem is:  
1- 0.5  
2- 6/20  
3- 3/20  
4- 1/20

Comment: @opeer That is correct.

Answer (score 0):

An order like e.g. WMMWMW means that the first chair is for a woman,
the second for a man, et cetera.

There are $\binom{6}{3}=20$ of such orderings, since you could say that $3$ chairs are picked out of $6$ to be the chairs of women.

$X=1$ corresponds with orderings starting with W and there are $\binom{5}{2}=10$ such orderings. This because from the other $5$ chairs $2$ are picked out to be the chairs of women again.

Can you take it from here?